# Running Jupyter Server on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, anaconda, jupyter

I have followed the directions at http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html to set up a jupyter server. I am able to run it via the anaconda prompt and get the following output:

```
C:\Users\adamimos>jupyter lab --ip=* --no-browser
[I 16:10:53.627 LabApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from C:\Users\adamimos\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 16:10:53.627 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\adamimos\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 16:10:53.798 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\adamimos
[I 16:10:53.798 LabApp] 0 active kernels
[I 16:10:53.798 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 16:10:53.798 LabApp] https://DESKTOP-TCCSP57:9999/
[I 16:10:53.798 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 16:11:37.581 LabApp] 302 GET / (172.25.101.65) 1.00ms
```

On the same machine running the server, I can then connect by typing in the browser: https://172.25.101.65:9999

However, when I go to another computer and try to do the same thing using the global ip address, I get a "took too long to respond." error. I have tried turning off firewalls on both computers.

Comment: what if you `ping` one computer from the other?

Comment: I get the following:Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 37 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss

Comment: Right, so that sounds like a networking problem, not a problem with Jupyter.